# Can the information entered into a Cognito Form be automatically sent to an email address upon submission?

Tags: cognito-forms

I have build a website for a finance company.  The Cognito Form is on the website as an application form.  I would like the information sent automatically to the finance company's email address (as soon as the form is submitted) without having to log into Cognito Forms. The finance company needs to know the exact moment the application for finance comes in. The finance company can not possibly log in to Cognito Forms 24/7 to check if there are any finance applications.

Answer (score 2):

Yes Cognito Forms can send email notifications to one or more recipients letting them know  that a form submission occurred with the  option of also including the form values filled out as well.

Under Form Settings for your form there is a checkbox called "Receive email notifications".
Add one or more email addresses separated by semicolons, click include details to include the data submitted with the form.