# Forward Cognito Forms responses to my email address

Tags: cognito-forms

How can I setup Cognito Forms to forward or send entries to my email address?

Answer (score 0):

I am a developer for [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com/).

This questions was addressed previously in another [Stack Exchange question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/65392/can-the-information-entered-into-a-cognito-form-be-automatically-sent-to-an-emai).

To add to this we have released a [blog post](http://blog.cognitoapps.com/how-do-i-set-up-email-confirmations-and-notifications) outlining the process of setting up email notifications and confirmations.